# Alternative to /etc/network/interfaces on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, interface

In ubuntu 18.04, I found that there is one more requirement for the /etc/network/interfaces configuration to work.

I got information that I could fix it by adding the ifupdown setting to the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file, but it did not work.

I could manually apply a static ip through the ifdown and ifup commands, but at boot time it only worked with dhcp, so I could not avoid big and small collisions.

Can I get accurate information about these recent changes?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 [uses netplan](https://netplan.io/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Gerald Schneider, Ubuntu 18.04 uses by default netplan.
Here is a good website explaining how to use it:

https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/

If you want to see about the release notes for the changes for the 18.04 version you can find them here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes